# How do I initialize a global variable with @MainActor?

Tags: swift, swift-concurrency

I would like to have some sort of global variable that is synchronized using `@MainActor`.

Here's an example struct:

```swift
@MainActor
struct Foo {}
```

I'd like to have a global variable something like this:

```
let foo = Foo()
```

However, this does not compile and errors with `Call to main actor-isolated initializer 'init()' in a synchronous nonisolated context`.

Fair enough. I've tried to construct it on the main thread like this:

```swift
let foo = DispatchQueue.main.sync {
    Foo()
}
```

This compiles! However, it crashes with `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION`, because `DispatchQueue.main.sync` cannot be run on the main thread.

I also tried to create a wrapper function like:

```swift
func syncMain<T>(_ closure: () -> T) -> T {
    if Thread.isMainThread {
        return closure()
    } else {
        return DispatchQueue.main.sync(execute: closure)
    }
}
```

and use

```
let foo = syncMain {
    Foo()
}
```

But the compiler does not recognize `if Thread.isMainThread` and throws the same error message again, `Call to main actor-isolated initializer 'init()' in a synchronous nonisolated context`.

What's the right way to do this? I need some kind of global variable that I can initialize before my application boots.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One way would be to store the variable within a container (like an `enum` acting as an abstract namespace) and also isolating this to the main actor.

```swift
@MainActor
enum Globals {
  static var foo = Foo()
}
```

An equally valid way would be to have a "singleton-like" `static` property on the object itself, which serves the same purpose but without the additional object.

```swift
@MainActor
struct Foo {
  static var shared = Foo()
}
```

You now access the global object via `Foo.global`.

One thing to note is that this will now be lazily initialized (on the first invocation) rather than immediately initialized.
You can however force an initialization early on by making any access to the object.

```swift
// somewhere early on
_ = Foo.shared
```

---

### Bug in Swift 5.5 - 5.9 (fixed in 5.10)

**`@MainActor` won't initialize `static let` variables on the main thread. Use `static var` instead.**

```swift
@MainActor
struct Foo {
  static let shared = Foo()
    
  init() {
    print("foo init is main", Thread.isMainThread)
  }
    
  func fooCall() {
    print("foo call is main", Thread.isMainThread)
  }
}
```

```swift
Task.detached {
  await Foo.shared.fooCall()
}
// prints:
// foo init is main false
// foo call is main true
```

This is a bug (see issue [58270](https://github.com/apple/swift/issues/58270)) that's been [fixed in Swift 5.10](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/69607).